# Automatically dismiss a chat message on clicking the notification

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, desktop-notifications

When I receive a reply/tag on chat, the 'notification bubble' must be clicked in order to dismiss the message:

[image]

I have desktop notifications enabled, but however clicking the notification to go to the chat message does not dismiss it (from both within the same tab/window, and from other browser tabs):

[image]

Surely it'd make sense for the chat message to be dismissed when the desktop notification is clicked, but however I foresee some potential issues with this:

- Not possible to act on when the user dismisses the notification
- Not possible to distinguish between clicking 'X' (which we would assume the user doesn't want to mark the message as read) and clicking on the *notification* to dismiss it

Can the desktop notification automatically dismiss chat messages when clicked on?

Comment: This is a good feature request that I always forgot to post. I thought the second limitation can be solved, but seems it'll be hard since there's `click` event handler, but `close` is deprecated (Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)). Anyway, the current notification only focuses the browser when clicked, but doesn't highlight the particular reply. If by any way, it can "click" the notification bubble (use API, or... I dunno), then it should be perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem like it *should* be possible, as the Notification `onclick` handler [is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclick) by all major browsers except IE (which doesn't support desktop notifications [at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/Notification), anyway).

As for your second concern, technically that shouldn't be a problem: there are separate `onclick` and `onclose` events, but unfortunately, `onclose` is no longer listed in [the spec](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org), so it may or may not be supported.

There's also a [`sticky`](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#api) attribute listed in the spec that might make your concern more relevant if included in a future version of the API, as currently Safari does not have a close button on notifications created this way; they will disappear in a few seconds, so it's a bit hazy as to when/how a particular notification was closed.

Did the user swipe the notification away, or did it just time out? Presumably, a "sticky" notification would remain on the screen in the way that these notifications currently do in Chrome and have a close button.

For now, though, using `onclick` should suffice. In my testing, the `onclick` event was only triggered when the user actually clicked on the notification to act on it (i.e. clicking the close button will not trigger the `onclick` handler). So, it would be safe to assume that if `onclick` is triggered, the chat notifications can be cleared (seems like DOM manipulation or a server call could take it from here).